# OpenCV 3.0 MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

OpenCV 3.0.0 provides the following motion models:

- MOTION_TRANSLATION
- MOTION_EUCLIDEAN
- MOTION_AFFINE
- MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY

What transformation does the model MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY do?

Answer (score 0):

According to OpenCV documentation for [findTransformECC](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga7ded46f9a55c0364c92ccd2019d43e3a):

- MOTION_TRANSLATION sets a translational motion model; warpMatrix is 2×3 with the first 2×2 part being the unity matrix and the rest two parameters being estimated.
- MOTION_EUCLIDEAN sets a Euclidean (rigid) transformation as motion model; three parameters are estimated; warpMatrix is 2×3.
- MOTION_AFFINE sets an affine motion model (DEFAULT); six parameters are estimated; warpMatrix is 2×3.
- **MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY sets a homography as a motion model; eight parameters are estimated;`warpMatrix` is 3×3.**

Comment: Could you provide an example of HOMOGRAPHIC transformation? The other three are easy to understand and visualize 1)translation- shifting 1)euclidean-shifting + rotation ,3)Affine - shift +rotate+shear, but I am not understanding what homography does?